# Mongoose ValidationError Path required that is out of subdocument array bounds

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, subdocument

This error is super wacky. It doesn't always fail, but when it does it looks like this.

I have some code that changes the "code" (a one character string) of elements in a subdocument array. It goes through each goal, checks to see if there's a change to be applied, and if so, applies it.

```
for (i = 0; i < user.goals.length; i++) {
  if (transformsMap[user.goals[i].code]) {
    user.goals[i].code = transformsMap[user.goals[i].code]
  }
}
user.goals.sort(function (a,b) {return a.code.charCodeAt(0) - b.code.charCodeAt(0))
```

When I save it, sometimes I get an error like this:

```
'goals.3.code': 
  { [ValidatorError: Path `code` is required.]
```

...but `3` in this case, is *the length of the goals array*. ie **there is no goals.3 subdocument**. I've tried logging `user.goals` and `user.goals.length` right before validation and they both agree that there are only 3 elements in the array.

I am totally baffled.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's going to be tough to help unless you can provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure I sorted out a temporary solution at the time. Finally, 7 years later, I've actually figured out what's going on with these sorts of situations.

I had some different code today, where I would pull an object out of one array, modify it, then put it in a different array:

```
const goal = user.goals.id(goalId)
user.goals.pull(goalId)
goal.code = goal.code + ' DELETED at ' + new Date().toISOString()
user.goalsDeleted.push(goal)
```

...and I would check before saving, and `user.goals` would be `[]`, but then I'd get `[ValidationError] User validation failed: goals.0.code: Path goals.0.code is required`

but there WAS no `goals.0.code`. And I don't totally understand what's going on there, but I narrowed it down to the `goal.code = ...` line. My guess is that when I do that, it half-recreates goals.0 somehow. Frankly I think this is a mongo bug, but in the meantime my solution is to destroy the mongo object between pulling it off one array and putting it on the other array:

so now my first line looks like this:

```
const goal = user.goals.id(goalId).toObject()
```

TL;DR = don't modify a subdocument after you've removed it from an array (which I believe was also involved in the above code)

Answer (score 0):

How about adding more checks?  And also setting a default value if the if clause fails?

```
for (i = 0; i < user.goals.length; i++) {
  if (user.goals[i] && user.goals[i].code && transformsMap[user.goals[i].code]){
    user.goals[i].code = transformsMap[user.goals[i].code]
  } else {
    user.goals[i].code = "" // Whatever this is <-- default value.
  }
}
user.goals.sort(function (a,b) {return a.code.charCodeAt(0) - b.code.charCodeAt(0))
```

Comment: I've added checks, and the check right before saving yields that there are still only eg 3 items in the array, and the problem shows up with the fourth one.